# electron app update now crashing on http require statement

Tags: electron

I made a electron app a couple years ago. now like to update for a little bit diiferint usage.

When I try to run this after updating electron and libraries and import it is failing on the http requirement.

The long ago compiled app still works, but even the code for that if i copy it to new project also failed on this require line.

**Error in the console**

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require
     renderer.js:62
```

And below are the codes

**browser setup in index.js**

```
const path = require('path');


// Handle creating/removing shortcuts on Windows when installing/uninstalling.
if (require('electron-squirrel-startup')) { // eslint-disable-line global-require
  app.quit();
}

const createWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 200,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
    }
  });

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));


  // Open the DevTools.
  //mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
};
```

**failing request in renderer.js**

```
/* placeCall
 * Grab the SIP uri from the input box and send it to the codec.
 * Requires an account on the codec that can make calls.
 *   Send the authorization in the http header.
 */
function placeCall(){
    
    var uri = document.getElementById("sipuri").value;
    var xmldoc = '<Command><Dial command="true"><Number>' + uri + '</Number></Dial></Command>';
    var xmlLength = xmldoc.length;
    var sysIp = document.getElementById("sysip").value;
    
//  console.log("XMLDOC: " + xmldoc);
    
    var http = require("https"); <- CRASHES HERE ON LINE 62!
    
    var options = {
      "method": "POST",
      "hostname": sysIp,
      "port": null,
      "path": "/putxml",
      "rejectUnauthorized": false,
      "headers": {
        "content-type": "text/xml",
        "content-length": xmlLength,
        "authorization": "Basic dkeicjsmcielwoslkdddddd"
      }
    };

    var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
      var chunks = [];

      res.on("data", function (chunk) {
        chunks.push(chunk);
      });

      res.on("end", function () {
        var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
        console.log(body.toString());
      });
    });

    req.write(xmldoc);
    req.end();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the error is in the browser. seems like it has to run as electron app.
That must be that require is really a node.js operation.
Maybe this question is repeated elsewhere and this one can be deleted.